# Why isn't generic method able to infer a parameter type?

Tags: c#, generics

```
public delegate T GenDel<T>();

class Program
{
    public static void genMet<T>(GenDel<T> d) { }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {           
        genMet(new GenDel<string>(() => "Works"));
        genMet(() => "Works");
    }
}
```

In above example the generic method receives lambda expression as a parameter ( `genMet(() => "Works");` ), and from this lambda expression method is able to infer parameter types.

Why isn't method also able to infer parameter type in the next example, where instead of lambda expression we pass a delegate instance as a parameter:

```
        genMet(new GenDel(() => "Doesn't work")); // Error: Using the generic type 'GenDel<T>' 
                                                  // requires 1 type arguments
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Type inference only applies to generic *methods*, not generic types or their constructors.

Comment: So generic methods are only able to infer parameter types if arguments for these methods are instances of closed constructed types? In other words, it is not the job of GenMet method to "tell" GenDel delegate what are GenDel's parameter types?

Comment: @user1483278 The piont is that `GenDel` will never be able to infer it's generic argument, because it's a constructor.  It would need to be a method to infer it's generic argument.

Comment: I apologize for late reply. Thank you both for your help

Answer (score 4):

There's no type inference in your second example - you are explicitly giving the delegate type to use. In this case you need to provide the type parameter since there is no non-generic `GenDel` type.